# Change value of variable that's already set

Tags: jquery, variables

This might really be a very basic question, but I've already tried a couple of things and it doesn't seem to work.

I have this var:

```
w = $("#el").width();
```

And I want to change `#el`'s width **via the var**. So setting the width, by using the var `w` without re-using the whole `$("#el").width()`. How do I do that? I already tried the following:

```
w = 50;
w == 50;
w = "50px";
w == "50px";
```

But these don't seem to work.

So I want to use `w` in a function to set `#el`'s width. So I don't want to use `$("#el").width()` because I am going to use it a lot. I need to use that var.

Comment: can u explain clearly

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum After all I didn't really need it like that anyway. I put the element in a var and give the var a width, so that worked. Unfortunately your answer is not really what I need. You explain the basic usage of `width()` but I understand that. The thing that I didn't get to work was to set the width through a `var`. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make w hold the function

```
var w = (function() {
   var $el = $("#el"); //cache the query selector to only use once
   return function(x){
       if(typeof x ==="undefined"){
          return $el.width();
       }
       return $el.width(x);
   };
})();
```

...then you can do:

```
w();//get the width
w(50);//set the width
```

Comment: Why did you change it? After the edit, it makes a DOM call every time you access it, I know this is not my answer but I feel like I should suggest an edit, if you don't like it feel free to revert.

Comment: The previous version didn't work - keeping the function object is not enough, you need the instance too.

Comment: @sje397 Yes, because you need to bound the value of this (in modern browsers this is usually done with the .bind function, I did not assume a modern browser). See my edit, feel free to revert if you do not agree with it.

Comment: @sje397 Yes (fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kHu4n/ ). Note that we have a function invocation (the )() at the end) that closes over the cached selector in $el (closes as in a lexical closure). This is a _really_ powerful thing that JavaScript lets us do.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah realised just after I posted that comment... I've been away from js for a little while now :) I'm reminded how much I enjoy it. Time to fire up that node server.

Answer (score 5):

[`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) accepts a parameter.

```
 $("#el").width(100);//set width to 100
```

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is not really what I need. You explain the basic usage of `width()` but I understand that. The thing that I didn't get to work was to set the width through a `var`. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable isn't *live*. It's a copy of the width at the time it was assigned. Changing the variable won't change the actual width.

Instead you need to do this:

```
$("#el").width(50);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
w = $("#el").width();
```

Merely passes the value of el's width to w, not the reference. That means that w holds an integer equal to el's width at the time of making that statement.

In order to CHANGE the width of el, you just have to use the function parameter:

```
$("#el").width(50);
```

Not that using the function with the parameter changes the return type of the function. `$("#el").width(50);` doesn't return the new width, so you can't use the statement 
`w = $("#el").width(50);` In order to update both your variable AND the actual width based on that variable, it must be done like so:

```
w = 50;
$("#el").width(w);
```

Answer (score 1):

[see here](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
var w = $("#el").width();

 $("#el").width(w);
```

you can do this

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var w = 100;
$("#el").width(w);
```

See [width() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
w = 50;
```

*This will only change the variable value.*

```
$("#el").width(w);
```

*This should change element width.*